# haproxy generate / renew list of certs of letsencrypt

Tags: haproxy

Is there a way in haproxy to generate the letsencrypt certs and renew them automatically given a list of domains.

We would just  be need to specify the domains/sans ... and if the IP is pointed out correctly. certs will get created/renewed.